# Installing Cocoapods without admin rights

Tags: macos, cocoapods

I'm trying to install Cocoapods on a shared computer where I am not an admin.

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started

I've been following this guide.

I'm stuck at this step:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Am I supposed to replace PATH with the actual file path of the pod? e.g. /Users/eloy/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods.rb

Comment: Create the `.profile` file. It's said "To do this, create or edit the .profile file in your home directory".  Then add the corresponding content in it, and then do `gem install cocoapods --user-install`.

Comment: I do not have a home directory. I'm using a school Mac so everything I have at the moment is a screen with a network folder with my school ID as a name.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51280/where-do-i-find-my-user-folder-in-the-os-x-folder-hierarchy ?

Comment: I do not understand this section export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: am I supposed to replace PATH with the actual path to where my pod is installed or leave it like that?

Comment: Be less self-deprecating and just explain clearly what, exactly, you don't understand.

Comment: Check edit. Should I replace the PATH in the .profile file with the path of the installed pod

Comment: Just write theses line the the file `.profile`. Consider that file as a simple text file.